# How to downcast mutable structs not as references

Tags: rust

I have this trait and implementation:

```rust
#[async_trait]
pub trait AsyncKeyProvider {
    async fn get_key_async(&mut self, key_id: &str) -> Result<Option<Jwk>, ()>;
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

#[async_trait]
impl AsyncKeyProvider for GoogleKeyProvider {
    async fn get_key_async(&mut self, key_id: &str) -> Result<Option<Jwk>, ()> {
        {...}
    }

    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}
```

In order to pass it into my handler in actix-web, I'm passing through a `GoogleKeyProvider` like this:

```rust
let key_provider = web::Data::from(Arc::new(GoogleKeyProvider::default()));

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(key_provider.clone())
            .route("/validate", web::post().to(validate))
    })
```

With the handler doing this:

```rust
pub async fn validate(jwt_body: web::Json<JwtBody>, provider: web::Data<Box<dyn AsyncKeyProvider>>) -> impl Responder {
    let provider_object: &GoogleKeyProvider =  provider.as_any().downcast_ref::<GoogleKeyProvider>().expect("Wasn't a GoogleKeyProvider");
    match validate_jwt(&jwt_body.jwt, provider_object).await {
        {...}
    }
}
```

`validate_jwt` then tries to call a method on the `provider` struct like this:

```rust
async fn validate_jwt(jwt: &String, provider: &GoogleKeyProvider) -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {    
    let key_to_use = provider.get_key_async(<thing>).await.unwrap();
}
```

Which presents me with this error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*provider` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src\routes\validate.rs:48:22
   |
48 |     let key_to_use = provider.get_key_async(<thing>).await.unwrap();
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ `provider` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

As far as I can understand, this is happening because the result of my downcasting is a reference (due to `downcast_ref`), but I think I'd be wanting the plain `GoogleKeyProvider` type instead - I'm not sure on that though. I believe the provider needs to be mutable as the values inside it (see below) can change during the lifetime of the provider (it's intended to provide a temporary cache for some keys, and automatically update them if they're out of date)

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct GoogleKeyProvider {
    cached: Option<JwkSet>,
    expiration_time: Instant,
}
```

I'm not sure how to get this working with downcasting, though. Is anyone able to help me see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I believe you suffer froma XY problem. What's the point of using a `dyn Trait` and then down-casting it? You are just as hard-coupled to your impl as you can be, but you are also making your code unmaintainable by those downcasts. Why don't you just use `GoogleKP` directly ? Or if you want to do it properly and be decoupled from the impl, then just don't downcast. I fail to see the point of it

Comment: Yeah, part of this might just be a misunderstanding on my part. I've been piecing together bits and pieces of how to pass in a struct to methods through actix-web and probably got myself too bedded in - passing it as a trait seemed to be what I found suggested, which is how I ended up here, but then had no idea how to really do anything with that once it was in the method

Comment: Can't you just change `validate_jwt` to accept `&mut GoogleKeyProvider` and then use `downcast_mut`  to obtain it? Although I agree with @SvetlinZarev, with the explanation provided here it is not clear why you need to use dynamic typing.

Comment: Thanks both - I ended up using the direct GoogleKeyProvider, with a mutex inside the Arc to allow me to get access to it using `mutex.lock()`, which is probably what I should have been doing this whole time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to choice if get_key_async update somme thing at the struct.

The simple code below show you the error

```
trait Atrait {
    fn afn(&mut self) -> i32;
}

struct Astruct {}

impl Atrait for Astruct {
    fn afn(&mut self) -> i32 {
        2
    }
}

fn main()
{
    // test should be mutable
    let test = Astruct{};       
    let value = test.afn();
    
    println!("Value {}", value);
}
```

This work because afn(self) is not declared mutable afn(&mut self)

```
trait Atrait {
    fn afn(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Astruct {}

impl Atrait for Astruct {
    fn afn(&self) -> i32 {
        2
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let test = Astruct{};
    let value = test.afn();
    
    println!("Value {}", value);
}
```